# How to debug System.TypeLoadException errors in .NET?

Tags: c#, clr

I'm getting the following error on one of my referenced assemblies:

`` Could not load type 'System.Func`2' from assembly 'MyAssembly, ... ``

My first instinct was to see what [MSDN had to say about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeloadexception.aspx):

> TypeLoadException is thrown when the
> common language runtime cannot find
> the assembly, the type within the
> assembly, or cannot load the type.

It appears to be is saying that the CLR simply can't find the type? That might make more sense if this wasn't something that was in mscorlib. This was all built on top of .NET4 with VS2010, so there's no mono or other weird library issues. What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure your referenced assembly also is compiled for .NET 4?

Comment: Good catch my man! For some reason the build process fell back to v2 on the referenced assemblies. Now I need to figure out why those assemblies are building on v2, but they had previously been working fine. Oh my God, I spent so much time on this. If you want to answer this I'll give you the best answer thing.

Comment: See also [What could be causing a System.TypeLoadException in a Visual Studio Unit Test?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5735673)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that you have a mismatch in your versions. Make sure all your assemblies are compiled for .NET 4.

Answer (score 34):

I received this error after refactoring. I had two projects compiling to DLLs with the same name.

Check the "Assembly name" in the project's properties' "Application" section.

Comment: I made a seperate project for my unit tests with the same name as the original solution, oops.

Comment: Many years later and this just saved my bacon after a couple of hours of investigation

Comment: I had 2 projects that both were using the same Nuget package but different versions. I updated the Nuget package to be the same version for both projects and this resolved the issue.

Comment: I google'd this error and every solution I tried didn't work except this. In my case, I had just renamed my Xamarin.Android assembly and accidentally renamed my .Net Standard 2.0 project (common code for iOS/Droid) to be the same assembly. Making them unique, as per your suggestion fixed it.

Comment: I thought if I keep the same name for the dll and the exe, it should be able to load the library given that the extension are different. But I was **wrong**. Changing the name of the exe fixed the issue. 
It does make sense at some level actually. Both the exe and library projects are compiled as binaries and the runtime might not differentiate based on the extensions and hence, couldn't load two binaries with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I refactored some code out from a Console UI to a class library. I forgot that the Console UI was originally named the same thing as the new library I created.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure about your specific scenario, but the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (fuslogvw) is usually very helpful in debugging type load issues. More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Comment: Sorry about the 1.1 link. My bad. But how is the fusion log not relevant in debugging type load exceptions?

Comment: For future reference, you can make the link automatically go to the latest version by simply removing the parentheses at the end. So instead of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.71).aspx, you would have this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Comment: removing the downvote. I was confusing TypeLoadException with TypeInitializationException.

Answer (score 4):

You may also get this if you change the assembly you're trying to load but still have an old version in the GAC. It tries to load the GAC'ed version not what you reference in your VS project.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I moved a class from one project to another in a cleanup effort. After looking at all other possible reasons, reloaded each of the projects in my solution and everything worked.

1. Right Click on the project name in solution explorer
2. Select Unload Project
3. Right Click on the project name in solution explorer
4. Select Reload Project

Answer (score 1):

This problem may occur if you have different versions of NuGet packages installed across different projects. To identify these cases,

1. Right-click the solution in Solution Explorer and select "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution"
2. Select the "Consolidate" tab
3. For any identified packages, identify the version you want and click "Install" to consolidate the package to that version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception when I refactored to move some classes to their own library, and referenced a different version of the library it's trying to load in the new library (acquired with NuGet) than I had been using in the original project.

The thing that fixed it was to open the NuGet Manager in the old project, and update the appropriate package to be the same version I was using in my new library.