# Error: System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Currently I'm working with an inherited solution in VS.Net 2010 IN C#. When I run this solution and click any tab from the menu, the screen shows the following error:

Detalles de la excepción:

```
System.TypeLoadException: No se puede cargar el tipo 'PraxairUsuarioBL.EmpresaBL' 
del ensamblado 'PraxairUsuarioBL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' 
porque el método 'getall' no tiene implementación (no RVA).
```

I've PraxairUsuarioBL is referenced in the project.

One person i told me:
"This often happens when you have an assembly which is compiled against one version of another assembly, 
but is executed with a different version of that other assembly present. This allows the app to run, but when a method is invoked it may be missing, 
the definition may be different, etc. "

I think it is not a problem with the code. I am sure that error is the assembly. But what steps i have to follow to do it?

What is mean "no tiene implementación (no RVA)."?

Comment: Can not load type 'PraxairUsuarioBL.EmpresaBL' assembly 'PraxairUsuarioBL, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' because the method 'getAll' has no implementation (no RVA).

Comment: You can use fuslogvw.exe to find out which assemby is loaded, where it comes from, what its version is. That might help in determing if the correct assembly gets loaded. Maybe a stale version from the GAC gets loaded...

Comment: I've getAll() in my reference PraxairUsuarioBL.EmpresaBL, i've seen.

Comment: IN **PraxairUsuarioBL** I'Ve:
_obj / debug / Refactor_ I have PraxairUsuarioBL
_obj / debug / TempPE_ I have other dlls.
_obj / debug_ where I have: PraxairUsuarioBL, PraxairUsuarioBL (debug) DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput, build.force

-I deleted the bin folder and created bin / debug and PraxairUsuarioBL, PraxairUsuarioBL (xml), PraxairUsuarioBL (debug)

My question is, which is stored in the folder in obj? The references I have to use to run my web application is the obj folder?

In my solution I have references: PraxairUsuarioBL [runtime = v2.050 ..] should not be the version?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I've open the project in vs2008 and ta tan :). All work it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your issues is addressed in much detail within the related thread in SO - [What could be causing a System.TypeLoadException in a Visual Studio Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5735673/1437962)

In addition, you may also look at [How to debug System.TypeLoadException errors in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5691100/1437962).

One possible issue may be that you have a **mismatch in your versions**. Make sure all your assemblies are compiled for the targeted Framework, for example in .NET 4.0.

Comment: How i check that all your assemblies are compiled for the targeted Framework, for example in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and adding again the reference to the assembly solved the problem for me