# Using Spire.Doc in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, macos, exception, xamarin, spire.doc

Help me to correct this exception, idk what's that. I couldn't find any information about that. What do I need to do?

```
using System;
using Spire.Doc;
using Spire.Doc.Documents;

namespace TOC
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Document document = new Document();
        }
    }
}

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Spire.Doc.Document'
from assembly 'Spire.Doc, Version=5.2.48.3040, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: 
Could not load type 'Spire.Doc.Document' from assembly 
'Spire.Doc, Version=5.2.48.3040, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3'.
```

I tried to create the solution again, then the problem disappeared and appear another one.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in 
Spire.Doc.Document:ᜤ (): IL_0003: pop       


at Spire.Doc.Document..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at TOC.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in 
/Users/mac/Documents/Csharp/TOC/Program.cs:11 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: 
Invalid IL code in Spire.Doc.Document:ᜤ (): IL_0003: pop       


at Spire.Doc.Document..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at TOC.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in 
/Users/mac/Documents/Csharp/TOC/Program.cs:11
```

It looks like so weird...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735673/what-could-be-causing-a-system-typeloadexception-in-a-visual-studio-unit-test

Comment: What concerns the names, the problem doesn't conclude in them. Idk where is "Configuration Manager" in Xamarin but it uses x86 instead of x64 mode but idk how to set it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to contact Spire.Doc vendor as,

1. Mono CLR is different from .NET CLR, and therefore the obfuscated assembly optimized for .NET might not work for Mono. They should provide you probably another obfuscated version.
2. Mono API is not 100% the same as .NET API, so you need the vendor to confirm that they fully test the product against Mono.
3. Don't simply rely on MoMA for compatibility testing. That's only a prototype and it only provides very basic functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I have found the answer (June 10, 2014): "Our product is functional in platforms such as .NET, WPF and Silverlight. And it doesn’t support Xamarin using Mono at present.
We are very sorry.
If you get any questions, welcome to get it back to us.
Regards,
Benjamin
E-iceblue support team". It's sad.. Anyway, thank you!