# PRISM Unity RegisterType fails

Tags: c#, unity-container, registration

I am using C# 4.7.2 and PRISM Unity 6.2.0

There's an interface, which looks like this

```
using System;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public interface IMyAnswer
    {
        Guid GUID { get; set; }

        dynamic Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and there's a class implementing that interface:

```
using System;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    internal class MyAnswer: IMyAnswer
    {
        public Guid GUID { get; set; }

        public dynamic Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to register the type like this

```
container.RegisterType<IMyAnswer , MyAnswer>();
```

container is of type IUnityContainer.

A System.TypeLoadException is thrown 'The Type IMyAnswer could not be loaded'

I removed the line and everything worked as before. I wrote the line again and the same exception occurred again. I removed the line again, but then the following registrations threw the same exception, even though they didn't before.

Can anyone help me here, please?

**Addition:**

The interface is located in a different project than the class. Wasn't and isn't a problem in case of several other registrations.

The version of the project / dll which contains the interface is mentioned in the error event as 1.0.0.0. I didn't know whether it's the file version or the assembly version. So I changed both numbers to different values. I removed the reference, cleaned and built the dll with the interface, added the reference again. Cleaned and rebuilt the dll containing the class. Both of the builds succeeded. I ran the application and the error is the same. The interesting part is now, that the version which is mentioned in the error is still 1.0.0.0.

Is it possible, that through all the builds nothing has changed at all?

**Addition 2:**

Assuming the name of the dll containing the interface would be MyInterfaces.dll. The Logger states this:

*C:\Path\MyInterfaces.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file*

The pdb file does exist in C:\Path. There are no restrictions on reading or writing neither on the folder or on the file itself.

**Solution:**
It turned out to a building problem. The solution is described here:
[Visual Studio Build seems not to use current projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295969/visual-studio-build-seems-not-to-use-current-projects)

Comment: Does it act the same way if `MyAnswer` is `public`?

Comment: Yes, it does. The Exception points to the interface, not the class. I registered several classes in the exact same way without any problems. But I can't find a difference. I tried to declare Answer as object instead of dynamic. Changed nothing.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009187/34092 help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it doesn't. But please have a look at the recent update of my post.