# Visual Studio Build seems not to use current projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, C# 4.7.2

My Solution contains currently nine different projects. A build succeeds without any error messages. When I run the application, a TypeLaodException is thrown, *The Type Namespace.AClassName* could not be loaded.

The weird thing is, that there isn't any class named *AClassName* anymore. BUT, the mentioned class did exist in a former version.

I cleaned the solution, startet a build, same error. I rebuilt the solution, same error. Cleaned than rebuilt the solution, same error.

Apparently, the build is not correct. But what can I do to ensure, that the build runs correctly?

Comment: Try to manually delete the `bin` and `obj` folders.

Comment: ...and the User Temp folder(s) content. Sometimes (in earlier releases of VS 2017) a left-behind piece did interfere with the build.

Comment: What/where are the temp folders? For now, deleting the content ob obj/debug solved the problem. Thank you very much to everyone, who helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If manually deleting the folders `bin` and `obj` as suggested in the comments is not working, I will also delete de `.vs` and there are a few things you can try:

- Unload the projects, and search in the `.csproj` for any reference to
  the Old-Deleted `AClassName`. Check also that there is no namespace related to it. 
  You will have to do it in the project where originally was the class, but I will recommend to search in all 9 projects.
- Check if there is any Project Dependency in the Configuration Manager related to the project where the `AClassName` was.
- I would also restart my machine, delete temp folder and run VS As administrator.

Comment: The .csproj file only contains a reference to project, where the AClassName was located in, but it doesn't contain a reference to AClassName itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean Solution.
2. Clean Debug & Bin folder.
3. Make sure all project reference are from Project libraries (it should not be directly from Bin folder).
4. Make sure all interconnected project build on same .net platform (4 , 4.5 or 4.6 ).
5. Build and try to run.

Comment: Cleaning the debug & bin folder is not enough. I needed to clean the obj/debug folder as well. Cleaning bin/debug AND obj/debug solved the problem.