# Publish on Azure Website unexpected behavior

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, publish, datacontext

I have a web project, which works fine on local PC. But when I publish it on Azure Website, I get an error:

> Could not load type 'Infrastructure.Asset.AssetContext' from assembly
>   'Infrastructure'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Infrastructure.Asset.AssetContext' from assembly 'Infrastructure'.

where AssetContext is DbContext from another project inside solution. As I understand, this assembly is not published correctly on Azure. So, I removed all files on Azure Website via Kudu and republish again. The same. I try to connect to remote Db from my local - it works. I tried to rebuild solution, reopen Visual Studio etc. Nothing happened

Why it can be happened, what is wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Can you please reference the nugets that your Infrastructure DLL is using to your <consuming> DLL? Chances are your project is trying to load AssetContext without some of the dependent DLLs being missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar SO thread [What could be causing a System.TypeLoadException in a Visual Studio Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735673/what-could-be-causing-a-system-typeloadexception-in-a-visual-studio-unit-test), I think which answers are valuable for your current issue.

Please follow the figure below to get the information of what platform you used is on Azure Website, then to select the current mode in Visual Studio to build and publish.

[image]