# TypeLoadException with D3DotNetAPI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, typeloadexception

I'm trying to use the D3DotNetAPI to create a Windows Phone 7 application.

Here is the link with the documentation : [D3DotNetAPI documentation link](https://github.com/HarleyCarter1234/D3DotNetAPI)

I'm just trying to follow the sample and to do this :

```
D3Explorer explorer = new D3Explorer(Region.EU);

//Career data for Battletag Gaidin#2380
Career myCareer = explorer.GetCareer("Gaidin", 2380);
MessageBox.Show("Has killed "+ myCareer.Kills.Monsters+" monstters, with "+ myCareer.Kills.Elites+" elites.");
```

And I throw this exception :

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
   at D3DotNetAPI.D3Explorer.TryGetData[T](String url, T& requestedObject)
   at D3DotNetAPI.D3Explorer.GetCareer(String battleTagName, Int32 battleTagCode)
   at d3.MainPage..ctor()
```

I'm not sure, but my exception can be similar with [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691100/how-to-debug-system-typeloadexception-errors-in-net)

PS : The same example works fine on a Win32 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto Answer :

ISerializable is not available in WP (WP = a part of .NET framework)