# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Func`2'

Tags: c#

I'm getting a System.TypeLoadException in my code with the following description:

`` Could not load type 'System.Func`2' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 ``

Here's basically what I'm doing near the error, sans try-catch and other stuff that's non-essential to the logic:

```
// assembly is an Assembly object
// derived is of type Derived, which is declared in assembly
// this line works fine
derived = assembly.CreateInstance(derivedClassName, true) as Base;

// this is fine    
derived.Foo();

// Exception happens here
derived.Bar();
```

Here's the basics of Base:

```
public abstract class Base : SomeOtherClass
{
    protected Base() : base() {}

    public void Foo()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Here's the basics of Derived:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    // overrides SomeOtherClass.Foo(), which is the only abstract method
    protected override void Foo()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your environment? Is this a desktop app? windows store/runtime app? web app? Which version of the .net framework is your app targeting?

Comment: Where is `Bar()` defined?

Comment: You guys were on the right track. `Derived` and `Base` were defined in separate projects, and I just realized that they target different versions of .Net. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the issue. `Base` and `Derived` are defined in two separate projects which target two different versions of .NET. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691100/how-to-debug-system-typeloadexception-errors-in-net) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The only `mscorlib`s which lack this generic type are versions prior to 2.0. Check that you have not references to any of those versions.

Comment: Incorrect! The type ``Func`2`` (or `Func<,>` in C# syntax) or ``Func`2[T, TResult]`` to name the type arguments, was new in .NET 3.5. In .NET 2.0 the only of these delegates was ``Action`1``. The general `Func` and `Action` delegates came with Linq.

Comment: You are welcome. As an example, the .NET 2 type `List<>` has a method `ConvertAll<>` that corresponds to Linq's `Select<,>` method. The `List<>.ConvertAll<>` method takes a delegate `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` which in signature and return type is entirely equivalent to the later `Func<T, TResult>` type.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with the C++/CLI project. I could not use classes from C++/CLI DLL in the C# project. I could load assembly from code (Assembly.LoadFrom) and I could create instance of my class using Reflection (Assembly.CreateInstance) but I still received TypeLoadException if I tried to use class in the C# code.

My issue is Executable and Dll had same name.

- SomeProject.dll
- SomeProject.exe