# Loading the type from the correct dll

Tags: c#, dll

I installed a nuget package which installs dlls *StoreLibrary.dll, Clients.Directory.dll* and *Clients.Directory.Platform.dll*. When I try to create an instance of a class in the *StoreLibrary.dll*, I get the 
TypeLoadException saying Could not load type **'Client.Directory.Certificate'** from assembly 'Client.Directory'. When I explored the dll I found the type **'Client.Directory.Certificate'** is in *Clients.Directory.Platform.dll* and not in 
*Clients.Directory.dll*. Also I found both the dll have the same namespace 'Client.Directory'. How can I make the runtime to look for the type in the correct dll which is *Clients.Directory.Platform.dll*? I found similiar question here for TypeLoadException but 
the answers are not resolving my issue.

Comment: The location of a type is known at compile time.  It should know that it need to go into Clients.Directory.Platform.dll for that particular type regardless of the namespace.  It's likely that there is something else causing Clients.Directory.Platform.dll itself from loading.  There should be more detail in TypeLoadException that might explain what's actually going on.

Comment: The inner exception is null. I can see the Clients.Directory.Platform.dll without warning/error under project Reference.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691100/how-to-debug-system-typeloadexception-errors-in-net