# Resolve System.TypeLoadException in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, sqlite-net

I am converting a project in .NET Core 3.1. But for some reason the `System.TypeLoadException` exception is being raised in my code:

```cs
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DataContext() : base() { }
    
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }
}

services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(DatabaseConnectionString));
```

I’ve got an error on this line:

```cs
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

with the following message:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Create' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Query.Internal.SqliteQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, Version=3.1.0.0,
```

Is there any solution to stop this exception from being raised?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug System.TypeLoadException errors in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691100/how-to-debug-system-typeloadexception-errors-in-net)

Comment: No, this is not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. I had to make sure the entity framework version for my Sqlite package(s) were the same as the one(s) that I used for my project(s) that defined the database contexts...

[image: Sqlite Packages]

[image: Entity Framework Packages]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced very much similar issue. It turned out to be a nuget cache issue. Clear the nuget cache in Visual Studio menu Tools → Options → NuGet Package Manager → General.