# "Exception has occurred: TypeLoadException" when running .net dll on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am porting a .net dll to linux,
so I installed dotnet SDK under WSL2 "Ubuntu 20.04" on a Windows machine
I build my dll tageting dotnet 6.0.

For testing I import the dll into a python script using pythonnet clr.
and run the script on Ubuntu20.04 machine.
When I run the script I get the following error

```
  Exception has occurred: TypeLoadException
Could not load type of field 'MyWorkSpace.MyClass:_updateWatchdog' (37) due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100004a from typeref (expected class 'System.Timers.Timer' in assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Timers.Timer member:(null)  at (wrapper managed-to-native)
System.RuntimeType.GetFields_native(System.RuntimeType,intptr,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.RuntimeType/MemberListType)
at System.RuntimeType.GetFields_internal (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.RuntimeType+MemberListType listType, System.RuntimeType reflectedType) [0x0001b] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
at System.RuntimeType.GetField (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x00015] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0
at System.Type.GetField (System.String name) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0
at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.CreateClass (System.Type type) [0x00079] in <3972e4befd8f45a1b7c0e96a8f1f659a>:0
at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.GetClass (System.Type type) [0x00015] in <3972e4befd8f45a1b7c0e96a8f1f659a>:0
at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.GetAttribute (System.String name, System.Boolean guess) [0x0008e] in <3972e4befd8f45a1b7c0e96a8f1f659a>:0
at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.tp_getattro (System.IntPtr ob, System.IntPtr key) [0x00073] in <3972e4befd8f45a1b7c0e96a8f1f659a>:0
```

I googled the problem and suggestions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691100/how-to-debug-system-typeloadexception-errors-in-net) which mention assembly mismatch as a cause for this problem.

So I checked [dotnet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) and found that this assembly is supported in dotnet 6 ,5 and Core 3.1.

I rebuilt the dll again using dotnet 3.1 on WSL ubuntu 20.04 running on Windows machine using dotnet 3.1 and Iget the same problem.
Also I tried to build the project on Visual studio 2019 running on Windows 10 machine using dotnet 3.1 and dotnet 5
but all trials result in the same error .

How can I overcome this problem?

update: this the test script i am using

```
import clr
import os

dll_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), ("mydll_l") + ".dll")
clr.AddReference(dll_name)
from MyNameSpace import MyClass
_MyObj = MyClass()
temp = _MyObj.GetTemperature()
print(temp)
```

update 2: Here is my project file on WSL .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="somedll">
      <HintPath>.\somedll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.1-dev-00947"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" Version="4.3.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why are you using Python to test whether .NET Core is installed or not? Just run eg `dotnet --version`. Right now you're getting errors caused by your Python script, not .NET Core. Perhaps you're missing some `using` clauses or references. You didn't post your Python script so one can only guess

Comment: Did you download the latest version runtime version of core? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not testing whether .Net core is installed or not, I am testing my dll.
I am using the same python script with windows version of the dll without causing problems, which means the python script is not causing problem.

Comment: Post the script then. The error says that a BCL type can't be found. That can happen if the correct runtime is missing or the type wasn't included.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I installed a fresh version from dotnet 6.0 SDK on my development machine and a fresh version of dotnet 6.0 runtime on my test machine

Comment: Post something *we* can copy inside our own WSL terminals and run to reproduce the problem. `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` isn't some third-party assembly, it's part of .NET itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I have updated my post with the python script

Comment: Can you actually resolve the System.Timers.Timer type from within your python script (not using your library)? I am not so sure that the problem is with your DLL...

Comment: I think it is a culture issue.  You are getting a time error when you are setting a temperature.  It looks like the culture is neutral : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral  See : https://andrewlock.net/dotnet-core-docker-and-cultures-solving-culture-issues-porting-a-net-core-app-from-windows-to-linux/

Comment: Side note: Why do you have an explicit package reference for System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in your C# project file? It should be part of the .NET 6 BCL and not require importing a nuget package...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace
I did a simple application after your question
build using csc and run using mono and it's working
and its working

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, regarding adding an explicit package reference for System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in my C# project file, I just did it for testing because this is the assembly containing System.Timers namespace.

Comment: @jdweng, error appears when I try to execute `from MyNameSpace import MyClass`, the execution don't reach the temperature reading command .

Comment: You have to add a reference to System.Timers.Timer to the package reference (see you csproject).  In VS you usually in Solution Explorer under references is where it gets added including the version.

Comment: I tested the dll using c# application instead of the python script.
and it's working fine.
So the problem was not from python script or dll, the problem caused by pythonnet running on Linux.